# Some beans seem not to have been injected by Spring shortly after web server startup

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, nullpointerexception

I'm struggling to figure out why (harmless) Null Pointer exception happens on our server running in production due to some bean not being set yet. This is the scenario:

1. Some users are working with web application
2. Web Application gets stopped
3. Web Application gets started
4. Almost immediately, Kerberos authentication takes places from client browsers probably still running active scripts
5. NPE occurs on Kerberos Service Authentication Provider, trying to call UserService (implementation of UserDetailsService) -- having couple of more security checks, resulting in NPE due to expected bean is NULL

The stacktrace fragment can be found at the end of question.

I could not reproduce this on development environment, so I hope to see ideas on why this might be happening.

Note: `ZzzzSecurityContextService` has `lazy-init="true"`; Spring version is `2.5.1`.

```
Dec 10, 2012 10:14:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
        ...
Dec 10, 2012 10:14:13 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 33849 ms
Dec 10, 2012 10:14:15 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet ZzzzGwtClient threw exception
org.zzzz.system.security.SecurityDataAccessException: Error reading user 'Zzzzzz' info from the database.; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.zzzz.system.security.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:181)
    at org.zzzz.system.security.DelegatingUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(DelegatingUserDetailsService.java:21)
    at org.springframework.security.extensions.kerberos.KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(KerberosServiceAuthenticationProvider.java:89)
    at org.springframework.security.providers.ProviderManager.doAuthentication(ProviderManager.java:195)
    at org.springframework.security.AbstractAuthenticationManager.authenticate(AbstractAuthenticationManager.java:46)
    at org.zzzz.session.WebAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(WebAuthenticationFilter.java:117)
    at org.springframework.security.ui.AbstractProcessingFilter.doFilterHttp(AbstractProcessingFilter.java:252)
        ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at zzzz.services.ZzzzSecurityContextService.getStructureService(ZzzzSecurityContextService.java:241)
    at zzzz.services.ZzzzSecurityContextService.readSecurityContext(ZzzzSecurityContextService.java:50)
    at org.zzzz.system.security.SecurityContextService.getSecurityContext(SecurityContextService.java:41)
    at org.zzzz.system.security.UserService.loadUserByUsername(UserService.java:173)
    ... 29 more
```